# Decomposing a representation of the affine group

Tags: rt.representation-theory, harmonic-analysis

Consider the affine group $\operatorname{Aff}(2, \mathbb{R})$ consisting of matrices
\begin{equation}
  A = (g, t) =
 \begin{bmatrix}
   g_{11} & g_{12} & t_1 \\
   g_{21} & g_{22} & t_2 \\
   0 & 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $g \in \operatorname{GL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}^2$. This group acts on $L^2(\mathbb{RP}^2)$ by $Af(x) = f(A^{-1}x),$ where $x$ is a vector in homogeneous coordinates. Is it possible to give a direct integral decomposition of this representation into irreducible components? If so, can we use the decomposition to express $f \in L^2(\mathbb{RP}^2)$ as an integral over its projections onto the irreducible components (i.e. is there a Plancherel formula)?